# ng-repeat does not recognize update to model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am not able to iterate over the values of a model I am updating. I have the following controller

```
app.controller('VariantsController', ['$http', function($http){
    var ctrl = this;
    this.cars = []; // I get the cars eventually ...
    this.selected_car = null;

this.selectCar = function(car){
      ctrl.selected_car = car;
    }
```

When the user clicks on a "car" on the webpage, I update the controller's `selected_car`. The page updates appropriately to show the name of the selected car, but ng-repeat does not iterate over the `selected_car`'s properties.

The following is the relevant html (`variants` is the alias of the controller):

```
<div ng-show="variants.selected_car">
  <h6>{{variants.selected_car.name}}</h6> <!-- Updates without problem -->
  <table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="(key,val) in variants.selected_car.specs"> <!-- Problem! Does not iterate -->
      <td>{{key}}</td>
      <td>{{val}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I looked into this: [AngularJS: ng-repeat list is not updated when a model element is spliced from the model array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475601/ng-repeat-list-in-angular-is-not-updated-when-a-model-element-is-spliced-from-th) but the accepted answer states "Whenever you do some form of operation outside of angularjs ...". In this case, I am updating the model from within the controller so it should not have been a problem. Also, how would I use `$apply` in this case when I'm not explicitly using `$scope`?

`selected_car.specs` is an object with a lot of keys:

```
{
   ...
   mileage: 13.53,
   mileage_city: 23,
   mileage_highway: 32,
   power: 220,
   ...
}
```

Plunker (courtesy @Phil): http://plnkr.co/edit/ULSr2Tk5D7phTYW0t7Ys?p=preview

Comment: Whats your aversion to injecting $scope and attaching the var to $scope.selected_car? Would solve your problem.

Comment: Well, I would have to change a LOT of code.

Comment: If it's not working, you're going to have to change code anyway....

Comment: what is the structure of variants.selected_car.specs

Comment: Given that this would/should normally work it would be hard to help you without a runnable example that displays the problem.

Comment: @JamesKleeh Alright. Let me create a fiddle really quickly.

Comment: Made one for you though it works fine ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/Mhkud6jIs3FUxvPNYHiV?p=preview

Comment: @Phil Yes it does! But ... why? Let me stare at my code for a while.

Comment: @Phil It doesn't work now if I add proper data. Weird http://plnkr.co/edit/ULSr2Tk5D7phTYW0t7Ys?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, it's "length"!

I assume `ng-repeat` attempts to use the `length` property of whatever it's iterating and your "length" property is causing it to iterate incorrectly or not at all.

To solve this, I'd choose a different property name. Maybe "body_length" or something similar.

<kbd>[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qlYFvJsnWy5MktGRNMre?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Gotta steer clear of those internal property names ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your data is coming correctly.Might be there is a problem with accessing object. try printing your object variants.selected_car.specs. I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8F1KynQkAXiUWPWKXoWA?) for a demo to print key value table .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.3.4"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'}">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>{{val}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>


var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.obj={name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'}
});
```

Comment: `specs` is not an array. Besides, what are `key` and `val` above?

Comment: @slider, Now I got What you want. I will look into it. just give me a min.

Comment: Sorry for the delay Laxmikant. How do I check if the data is coming or not inside the template? With the simple object you have, it prints fine. But with a bigger object, it doesn't. If you look at the Pluker that I just added to my question, you may see the problem better.