# AngularJS : Unable to add a row in a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]I want to add the informations that i type in the form  in the table ;

Here's my form

```
 <section id="contact-info">


    <section id="contact-page">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="center">        

                <p class="lead">Import reports</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="row contact-wrap"> 
                <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
                <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>name *</label>
                            <input type="text" name="NameOfUploader" class="form-control" required="required" ng-model="r.NameOfUploader">
                        </div>
                       <div class="form-group">  
                            <label>DateOfUploade</label>
                            <input type="Date" class="form-control" ng-model="r.DateOfUpload" >
                        </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="t">Type of File</label>
                                <select 
                                    class="form-control" id="t" ng-model="r.TypeOfFile">
                                    <option>.word</option>
                                    <option>.xsl</option>
                                    <option>.pdf</option>
                                </select>
                            </div> 

                            <div class="form-group">
                            <label>file</label>
                            <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" fileread="r.file">
                        </div>                        

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  ng-click="saveDetails()">Import File</button>
                        </div>
                                    <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id_file</th>
                                <th>NameOfUploader</th>
                                <th>DateOfUpload</th>
                                <th>TypeOfFile</th>
                                <th>File</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat="r in reports">
                                <td></td>
                                <td>{{r.NameOfUploader}}</td>
                                <td>{{r.DateOfUpload}}</td>
                                <td>{{r.TypeOfFile}}</td>
                                <td>{{r.file}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>   

                    </div> 


                    </form> 
            </div><!--/.row-->
        </div><!--/.container-->
    </section><!--/#contact-page-->
```

Here's my java controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveDetails")
    public DetailsReport saveDetails(DetailsReport d)
    {
        detailsReportRepository.save(d);
        System.out.println(d.toString());
        return  d;

    }
```

Here's my Js controller

```
 //Save details of report

    $scope.saveDetails=function(){

          var fd = new FormData();
          var url='http://localhost:8080/saveDetails';
          fd.append("NameOfUploader",$scope.r.NameOfUploader);
          fd.append("DateOfUpload",$scope.r.DateOfUpload);
          fd.append("TypeOfFile",$scope.r.TypeOfFile);
          fd.append("file", $scope.r.file);

         console.log(fd);
         $http.get(url,fd,{
             transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
         })
         .success(function(data){

             $scope.reports.push(data);
            console.log(data);
             console.log($scope.reports);

         })
         .error(function(){
         });


    }
```

Any help? when i click on import report , i don't have error but the informations are not added to the table

Comment: when you do the $http.get does it go in the success or error callback?

Comment: success but it doesn't add anything , i have tried to put console.log($scope.r.NameOfUploader); just to see if it displays the value of the input and it works

Comment: so in the success function, data is ok and $scope.reports too? or in the callback in something odd?

Comment: No there's no error   at all

Comment: but it's added the new record in $scope.reports when you do console.log($scope.reports)?
Also, can you fill a plunker or similar to try?

Comment: $scope.reports.push(data);    have you getting new record in console.log($scope.reports) ?

Comment: I will update the post to add the image of what i get okay?

Comment: it adds  an empty row

Answer (score 0):

There may be a mismatch between between the mapping of 'data' and '$scope.reports' variable.

Can you please post log for both the values.

Comment: Me too i thought it could be the problem , for the log of both values i post the image

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this answer

[AngularJS: ng-repeat list is not updated when a model element is spliced from the model array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475601/ng-repeat-list-in-angular-is-not-updated-when-a-model-element-is-spliced-from-th)

by using `scope.$apply();`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem, if I understand right the console output, is that an array of one element is being added to $scope.reports instead of an object so an empty row is being printed because no data matches the r element.

In your controller you should add the individual elements if it's an array.

```
//Save details of report
$scope.saveDetails=function(){

    var fd = new FormData();
    var url='http://localhost:8080/saveDetails';
    fd.append("NameOfUploader",$scope.r.NameOfUploader);
    fd.append("DateOfUpload",$scope.r.DateOfUpload);
    fd.append("TypeOfFile",$scope.r.TypeOfFile);
    fd.append("file", $scope.r.file);

    onsole.log(fd);
    http.get(url,fd,{
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(data){
        if (data instanceof Array){
            for (i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
                $scope.reports.push(data[i]);
            }
        } else {
            $scope.reports.push(data);
        }
        console.log(data);
        console.log($scope.reports);
    })
    .error(function(){
    });
}
```

Comment: Still the same problem it shows me in the console :Object {id_file: 85, file: null, dateOfUpload: null, nameOfUploader: null, typeOfFile: null} wich means the data are not correctly send to the server isn't it?

Comment: yes, you are sending null values from the server, so no data is beign shown in the added row

Comment: but i am not sending null values i don't know where is the problem can you help please?

Comment: But that's problem of your server. You are returning an object with null values in file, dateOfUpload, nameOfUploader and typeOfFile. Check it in the server side

Comment: did you mean in java controlleur , i should test the return of saveDetails?

Comment: Yes, check the java part where you return the data for savedetails call

Comment: I check it , the system.out.println(d.toString()); gives me  null values i don't know why i am using the save of crud operations  .So what can be the problem?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing there so I can't help

Comment: I 'am saving an entity that i have to display in the table using the angular Js

Comment: Sorry, I can't help without seeing what you're doing. It would be better if you check the response and look when you populate the response data to see what you're doing wrong.