# ajax request in angular and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I'm trying to start a simple web page in which I wanna load data to a combobox from a request to my php script; The problem that I'm having is that when I load the page it doesn't load, but if i assign the function to a button it does but i have to press it twice for it to start working... I just can't figure out why that's happening, I have the next code in my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" for="pref-perpage">Categoría:</label>
       <select id="pref-perpage" class="col-lg-9 lindo">
               <option ng-repeat="result in search.vendor">{{result.nombreCategoria}}</option>
               <option selected="selected">[ Seleccione ]</option>
       </select>
</div> <!-- form group [Categoria] -->
```

this is my javascript:

```
  search.buscar = function()
  {

    $.ajax({
      url: "Busqueda.php",
      type: "get",
      success: function(response) {
          search.vendor.push({'nombreCategoria':response});
        var JSONObject = JSON.parse(response);

          for(var x in parsed){
          search.vendor.push(parsed[x]);
        }
```

and the kind of data that I want to fill the array with would be something like:

```
search.vendor = [{'nombreCategoria':'data'}];
```

If've also tried the $http method from angular but it does the same; I fill the combobox with fake data manually and I have no problem!

server response: [{"nombreCategoria":"ACCESORIOS"},{"nombreCategoria":"CPU"},{"nombreCategoria":"IMPRESORA"},{"nombreCategoria":"MONITOR"}]

Comment: Use the $http Anuglar service for get data, not $.ajax

Comment: Yeah, as i wrote before i already tried that...and worked the same...still having the same problem; actually that's "old", i'm using the $http right now and gives me the next error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o, in the line of the JSON.parse...

Comment: could you give us an example server response?

Comment: Yes, of course, the server response to that is: [{"nombreCategoria":"ACCESORIOS"},{"nombreCategoria":"CPU"},{"nombreCategoria":"IMPRESORA"},{"nombreCategoria":"MONITOR"}]

Comment: try replacing `search.vendor.push()` with `$scope.search.vendor.push()`

Comment: I got the same error man :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working with Gabriel in this project.
The soluction was to add the method `$scope.$apply();` after the .push() method...

So, the function looks like this:

```
search.buscar = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Busqueda.php",
        type: "get",
        success: function(response) {
            search.vendor.push({'nombreCategoria':response});
            var JSONObject = JSON.parse(response);
            for(var x in parsed) {
                search.vendor.push(parsed[x]);
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

By the way... I found the solution [here (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15476728)