# Angular JS order by filter not working for dynamic updates

Tags: php, angularjs

I have developed messaging functionality using php as backend and angular 1 on frontend. I am new to angularjs.

My ng-repeat code is

```
<div ng-repeat="m in messages | orderBy:'+created_at' track by $index">
```

This prints all my messages in correct order(latest messages first). SQL query returns `messages ordered by created_at descending`.

When I send a new message, I am adding that new message to `messages` object after inserting it in database. Code is

```
$scope.messages.push(angular.copy(response.data.data));
```

This adds new message at the end of the array.

I have also tried `unshift` method. It adds new message at the `0th` position.

In both cases, the new message is displayed at the start instead of showing after latest message. Its `created_at` value is set as current time stamp.

I want new message to be displayed after latest message.

Comment: I guess you will have to use scope.$apply() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475601/angularjs-ng-repeat-list-is-not-updated-when-a-model-element-is-spliced-from-th

Comment: @Hussain My ng-repeat is getting updated. But the new message is displayed at wrong position.

Comment: `<div ng-repeat="m in messages | orderBy:'+m.created_at' track by $index">` fixed the issue